# Using Moment.js, how do you convert a moment to a date or do calendar date comparisons?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs, date-comparison

If you have a moment which is a datetime.

```
var d1 = moment();
```

How do I convert `d1` to a `date` (losing time) so you can do math. I'd like to do..

```
var d1 = moment(); // convert this to a date.
var d2 = moment(); // convert this to a date.
```

These should return like this*;

```
d1.isBefore(d2) // false;
d1.isAfter(d2) // false;
d1.isSame(d2) // true
```

### Footnotes

```
* assuming d2 didn't occur after the day-rollover
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
moment().startOf('day')
```

That will shift the time to midnight (in most cases).

Answer (score 0):

## Using the two argument form of momement.js comparisons

I'm not sure of the easiest way to do this in that fashion, but the comparison methods are smarter than that.. This is why the `.valueOf` overrides weren't sufficient for the library.

```
d1.isBefore(d2); // same as d1 < d2;
```

But, the signature is

```
moment().isBefore(Moment|String|Number|Date|Array, String);
```

And, the second `String` argument corresponds to this

> Like moment#isAfter and moment#isSame, any of the units of time that are supported for moment#startOf are supported for moment#isBefore. Year, month, week, day, hour, minute, and second.

So simply run the same tests like this..

```
d1.isBefore(d2, 'day') // false;
d1.isAfter(d2, 'day')  // false;
d1.isSame(d2, 'day')   // true
```